# Fedora 17 can't access by the right password from the screensaver page

Tags: passwords, fedora, screensaver

I couldn't log my linux with the right passwd when screensaver locked the screen , but several days ago I can log in from the locked screen. Now when I choose "change users" to use the same passwd and username, I can access the current session.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 17 has not support from Fedora 19.